# adb pull not finding a file that's clearly there

Tags: android, powershell, adb

I've got a powershell script that I use to pull my database off of my Android phone while testing.

```posh
$appName = 'mobi.futurestate.timetracker'
$dbName  = 'database.sqlite3'

adb shell "run-as $appName chmod 644 /data/data/$appName/files/$dbName"
adb pull "/data/data/$appName/files/$dbName" "./$dbName"
Invoke-Item ".\$dbName"
```

But when I run it, I get the error

> remote object '/data/data/mobi.futurestate.timetracker/files/database.sqlite3' does not exist

However when I use Shell, and navigate to the location, I can see that it's clearly there.

[image]

Am I missing something? what do I need to do to be able to pull that thing down?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a device with an encrypted hard drive (mine is the Nexus 6 with forced encryption), the adb pull command will fail.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a permissions issue with getting files through run-as. Try copying the file with this instead.

`adb shell "run-as $appName cat files/$dbName" > "./$dbName"`